# redirect by file extension in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect all calls to aspx files in a specific sub-folder of the web to the same name and path with a .php extension.

For example
`/onlinehelp/default.aspx`  will go to `/onlinehelp/default.php`

`/onlinehelp/stuff/junk.aspx` will go to `/onlinehelp/stuff/junk.php`

It seems simple enough, but I can't get it to work.  I thought this would work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (/onlinehelp/.*)\.aspx$ http://www.mydomanin.com$1.php
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does that redirect currently not do anything, or does the URL come out different than expected?

Comment: Your code works for me. Is it giving any errors?

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Do you have other rules in this .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

thank you...it is working ....now.  must have been a caching problem.  curse the load balancers!!!  lol  sorry for the trouble.  I appreciate the responses

The .htaccess file is sitting in the subfolder /onlinhelp/ where I need the redirection to take place.